# Math issue when reading and using decimal datatype from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have stored 2 decimal currency in the mysql database in the decimal(15,2) data type. it has 2 column. one is DR and other one is CR

when i read all data using php and subtract total DR- CR some time I am getting result with multiple decimal like 8505.0800000001. why this happening?

```
    $total_dr=0;
    $total_cr=0;
    $balance=0;

    $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    { 

    $total_dr=$total_dr+$row['dr'];
    $total_cr=$total_cr+$row['cr'];

    $balance=$total_dr-$total_cr;

    echo '
        <tr>                   
           <td align="right">'.$total_dr.'</td>
           <td align="right">'.$total_cr.'</td> 
           <td align="right">'.$balance.'</td>
        </tr>
    ';

    }
```

here is some out put i got

```
533026.19   493497.31   39528.88
533026.19   502427.63   30598.56
533026.19   511367.07   21659.12
533026.19   520268.57   12757.62
533026.19   524521.11   8505.0800000001
533026.19   528773.65   4252.54
533026.19   533026.19   0
```

Comment: I would say PHP uses floating point variables.

Comment: Read the warning on this page.  Floating point math has known limitations.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not natively support the `DECIMAL(15,2)` format. Instead it uses floating point numbers.

My recommendation would be to have all numbers as `int` and do the decimal calculation at the very last moment.

Something like:

```
echo number_format($balance / 100, 2);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am very new to for php and mysql. what is the best datatype to save currency in my sql database. i fixed the issue  doing number_format($balance,2). But i want to do my project is a best way